# differences between vesa and fbdev Xorg drivers?

Tags: drivers, xorg

What are the differences between the 'VESA' driver and the 'fbdev' driver for Xorg? Both have no hardware acceleration a.f.a.i.k.

Answer (score 7):

```
 man fbdev
```

> *The fbdev driver supports all hardware where a framebuffer driver is available.*

---

```
man vesa
```

> *The vesa driver supports most VESA-compatible video cards. There are some known exceptions, and those should be listed here.*

They are written for different kinds of devices. Frame buffer devices do not have to be VESA-compatible (although an abstraction driver from VESA to framebuffer called [*vesafb*](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.4.4/Documentation/fb/vesafb.txt) exists), [or physically present](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb), for that matter.